# Drawing staircases in a loop but not getting correct results

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am trying to draw 7 staircases with a loop but I have missed something and not sure why it's not working. It draws the first staircase and then goes completely off track and doesn't put the pen back down and I'm not sure why.

```py
#Draw stairs 7 times
from turtle import*

#Stair repeat
for i in range (3):
    forward (25)
    left (90)
    forward(25)
    right(90)

#move to next stair
for i in range(7):
    penup()
    forward(25)
    right(90)
    forward(75)
    left(90)
    pendown()
```

My understanding is that the for loop would repeat the code, so if I want it to move for 7 separate stairs then the range is 7? This is obviously not correct though as it doesn't work. Hoping someone could point me in the correct direction as to why it's wrong.

Comment: First the first for-loop is executed completely, then the second.

Comment: If the first for loop is executed completely is there a way to make it so the code repeats seven separate times? As I thought the first for loop would be executed then move to the next position and repeat the first for loop but that does not seem to be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things seem amiss:

- The body of the `for i in range(7):` loop doesn't make sense. It never does any movement when the pen is down, so the turtle draws nothing.
- The `for i in range (3):` loop doesn't make sense either if you want to draw 7 stairs. What do you need to do 3 times here?

Beyond that, avoid `from turtle import *`. This is confusing and can lead to bugs, because it brings hundreds of functions into your namespace, creating potential name clashes and making it hard to tell which functions are yours and which belong to the turtle module. Better to `import turtle` or `from turtle import Screen, Turtle` and create a turtle instance.

Here's a rework that hopefully matches your intended result:

```py
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()
step_size = 25

for _ in range(7):
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(step_size)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(step_size)

turtle.exitonclick()
```

Based on the follow-up comment, if you want to draw staircases of 3 stairs 7 times, then nest your loops and add some code to reposition the turtle to wherever it needs to be to draw each staircase. For example:

```py
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()
step_size = 25

for i in range(7):
    t.penup()

    # whatever logic puts you in the right position for the next stair
    t.goto(-step_size * i, 1.5 * step_size * i)

    t.pendown()

    for _ in range(3):
        t.left(90)
        t.forward(step_size)
        t.right(90)
        t.forward(step_size)

turtle.exitonclick()
```

I don't know what your expected goal is, so you'll need to adjust this to match that, but the general approach should be the same.

Comment: So the for I in range(7) I thought this meant it would repeat the penup/pendown section 7 times as I am trying to draw 7 different set of stairs. The for i in range (3) this was to make the stairs the length I wanted it to be so it would run 3 times. I can't work out how to get the pen to move to a different location to draw the next set of stairs. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: So you want to draw 7 sets of 3 stairs? Then you need nested loops, 7 on the outside and 3 on the inside, with a repositioning movement (penup/pendown) after each outer loop pass. I'm not sure what layout you want though.

Comment: Thank you for your help. What you have explained there makes perfect sense. I was going about it all wrong. Again thankyou.